# How to get index value from start after sorting column in pyspark?

Tags: sorting, indexing, pyspark

I want to find median,after sorting i want the index value to start from 1 again how should I do that?
Here salary is a column which I want to sort and then I was adding index so i could could have index column starting from one because for median we need position.But the index is getting updated after sorting .I want the index to start from beginning again after sorting.

```
df1=df1.orderBy(Salary)

df1 = df1.select('Salary').withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you could add some example data and the expected output to your question. You also should add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to just find the **median**, then you can use the `summary` function and filter for the `50th percentile`:

```
df1.summary().filter(col("summary")=="50%").select(col("salary")).show()
```